# What's the deal with those raw eggs eaten by Rocky before training

Tags: nutrition, training

I'm entering on this *fitness* life now, aged almost 30. I never used to care about it, but I realize I'm late on this as I have stopped all my sporting life and become sedentary. I've been in the gym for about 2 months and I'm learning about training and nutrition stuff. I realized how much feeding before training is important to provide energy so I can put in my best on the activities. I've started eating fruit just before the training and this just made a big difference to my training.

So I started wondering what's the deal with the eggs eaten by Rocky in the first movie, where he eats about 3 raw eggs before starting training.

Comment: No sense in making a whole answer, but FWIW a raw egg or two in a smoothie is a quick easy way to get some protein and it doesn't affect the taste or consistency at all.

Comment: Don't forget Rocky was a poor brawler whos day job was as a muscle man for a mobster. Eggs were probably the best nutrition he could afford at the time.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr that is a good observation about the movie tho.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Eggs, by their nature, have a substantial amount of good protein in them, 6 grams in a large egg, along with the cholesterol and calories needed to sustain exercise. [In the 1890s, it was believed that cooking the egg removed some of the nutritional values](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2006/12/do_boxers_drink_raw_eggs.html) and this tradition was carried on through the worlds of bodybuilding and boxing as word-of-mouth "truth". I suspect some degree of machismo was involved as well, since many people find raw eggs to be nauseating, so choking them down was a way to demonstrate your self-control. [Modern science has since established](http://www.livestrong.com/article/466788-can-humans-digest-raw-eggs/) that humans can absorb 90% of the nutrition in a cooked egg, and only 50% in a raw egg, including the protein. Some exercise and raw-foods gurus have latched onto part of that science and claim raw eggs as a good source of protein with fewer calories, ignoring the [reduced protein aspect](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2483/do-raw-eggs-contain-protein-inhibitors). And, of course, raw eggs are a potential source of salmonella and e. coli, something they knew at the time of *Rocky*.

So, in short, it's bad science that was obsolete at the time the movie came out, which has since been discovered to be even more fallacious.

Comment: That's a nice explanation of the act of eating raw eggs as well the history behind it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The boxing world - especially in the era where the "Rocky" movies were made - is notoriously bad at developing new methods for nutrition and exercise based on research and findings.

The whole "drink raw eggs, run 5 miles every morning and beat this frozen pig"-method isn't really something you should strive for today.

Comment: Sure, specially in the pig part. haha. What I tried to say is what the role of the egg in this case, if its was like I said with the fruits, or like those who consume whey protein for training...

Comment: The egg part is okay, but why not just .. boil them, or make scrambled eggs? As far as I know, it's pretty much the same protein intake for 8 minutes work for something that will actually be nice to eat.